# Why won't pygame accept more than 2 keyboard inputs?

Tags: python, events, keyboard, pygame

In every game I make with pygame it won't register any more then 2 simultaneous key presses. (e.g. if I'm holding up and left to move it won't let me press space to fire.)  Is this software?  Hardware?  Is there anything I can do about it?

**EDIT:** I use a Digital Media Keyboard 3000 on one computer and it does pretty good.  According to KeyScan it can do about 6 keys at once.  The computer I code on OTOH, is a laptop and won't do more than 2 keys.  It is an HP Pavillion Entertainment PC.  Input capturing is like so:

```
`for e in pygame.event.get():
     ## do stuff`
```

Both computers ran the same code when I tested them.  So I guess it is hardware.  Thanks everyone!

Comment: What type of keyboard are you using? If it's USB the likely hood of it being a hardware issue is relatively slim. EVen the cheapest keyboards seem to bottom out @ 3 or 4 simultaneous button presses before they go wonky. But a better question would be.. how are you capturing input?

Comment: I tested two applications on Windows XP that accept keyboard input: MS Word and gvim. Results were identical for both applications. When up and left arrow keys were held down, space bar input was not recognized. Oddly enough, other character keys were recognized while up and left were held down.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no experience with pygame, but is [probably a hardware issue](http://forums.logitech.com/t5/Keyboard-Hardware/Simultaneous-keypresses/m-p/34165). You can use the KeyScan program mentioned in one of the answers posted there to test your keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.sjbaker.org/wiki/index.php?title=Keyboards_Are_Evil

Answer (score 0):

This varies widely from keyboard to keyboard; it's cheap hardware design.